# Correct way to convert array<unsigned char>^ to std::string

Tags: c++-cli

I wanted to know what is the correct way to convert a managed `array<unsigned char>^` to an unmanaged `std::string`. What I do right now is this:

```
array<unsigned char>^ const content = GetArray();
auto enc = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII;
auto const source = enc->GetString(content);
std::string s = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(source);
```

Is there a way to marshal the `content` in one step to a `std::string` without converting to a `String^`?

I tried:

```
array<unsigned char>^ const content = GetArray();
std::string s = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(content);
```

but this gave me following errors:

```
Error   C4996   'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,cli::array<unsigned char,1> ^,false>::marshal_as': 
This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included.  
Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method.

Error   C2065   '_This_conversion_is_not_supported': undeclared identifier
```

Answer (score 2):

If the array is of plain bytes, then it's already ASCII encoded (or whatever narrow characters you're using). Converting to a managed UTF-16 `String^` is an unnecessary detour.

Just construct a narrow-characters string from the byte array. Pass a pointer to the first byte and the length.

```
array<unsigned char>^ const content = GetArray();
pin_ptr<unsigned char> contentPtr = &content[0];
std::string s(contentPtr, content->Length);
```

<sup><sup>I'm not at a compiler right now, there may be trivial syntax errors.</sup></sup>